# Unsupported config option for services

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  postgresql_database:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
    - POSTGRES_DB=Games
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"


    games.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}gamesweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Games.Web\Dockerfile
      depends_on:
      - "postgresql_database"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите `depends_on` за пределы `build`, чтобы это выглядело так:

```
games.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}gamesweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Games.Web\Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - "postgresql_database"
```